# Store button with image in to sqlite3 database

Tags: iphone, sqlite, insert, uibutton

I have a form(table view) which contains textfields and textview as subviews,I need to save the data filled in those fields.Hence I used sqlite3.Everything works fine,saving retrieving and displaying saved data.But in the table view,I have one cell which contains a button as subview.As we know that there's no concept called checkbox button in iphone.Therefore I used button and  added default image as subview shown in the following:

[image]

When the button is not selected,the image is unchanged.

Now that if the user selects the button the image changes to check mark indicating that the logic works every year as shown in the following:

[image]

Now my question is how can I save the button image in to sqlite3.I have used the following query to insert values:

```
NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO reminders(name,event,date,tim,bfr,num,bod,grp) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\",\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")", fieldOne.text, fieldTwo.text,fieldThree.text,fieldFour.text,fieldFive.text,fieldSix.text,textView.text,fieldSeven.text];
```

Similarly how can I save the button with image as subview in sqlite3.I heard that there is no concept like BOOL values storage in sqlite3.Instead it is stored as int values i.e. "0" as false and "1" as true.Hence I used the following query to insert the button image:

```
int selValue;

if(checkboxSelected == NO)
{
    selValue = 0;
}

else if(checkboxSelected == YES)
{
    selValue = 1;
}
NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO reminders(name,event,date,tim,bfr,val,num,bod,grp) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\",\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")", fieldOne.text, fieldTwo.text,fieldThree.text,fieldFour.text,fieldFive.text,isSelected,fieldSix.text,textView.text,fieldSeven.text];
```

In console the selValue is getting displayed as 1 if button's selected and 0 if not.

But I have a controller page called view edit reminder,where the user can view the saved reminder and edit for changes to happen.Now I have saved a reminder called Amma,there while saving I have selected Every Year button,but its not working even though the data inserted is getting retrieved for the reminder as shown below:

[image]

EDIT:

The code I have implemented for retrieving the data from sqlite3 database table:

```
ReminderClass *remind = [[ReminderClass alloc]init];
                remind.Name = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statment, 1)];
                remind.Event = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statment, 2)];
                remind.Date = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statment, 3)];

                remind.time = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statment, 4)]; 
                remind.numDays = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statment, 5)];
                remind.selString = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statment, 6)]];
                remind.number = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statment, 7)];
                remind.msgBody = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statment, 8)];
                remind.remGroup = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statment, 9)];
```

EDIT:

This is what I did for editing the content:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)atableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (aTable.editing) 
    {
        ReminderClass *rem = (ReminderClass *)[self.monthArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

        // Instantiate your detail/editor view controller,
        // and pass in the ReminderClass object to be edited.
        ERAddReminderViewController *rdvc = [[[ERAddReminderViewController alloc]initWithReminder:rem]autorelease];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:rdvc animated:YES];
    }

    [atableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Please help me out with your valuable suggestions

Thanks all in advance :)

Comment: Have you store the year selection value of 0 or 1 in your sqllite database?

Comment: @hiren443 Yeah I have stored the selection value

Comment: show your display code of editing your remainder

Comment: Yeah I have posted the code I used to retrieve the data when table view is in editing mode the **remind.selString** is what caused me the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setting:

```
int selValue;

if(checkboxSelected == NO)
{
    selValue = 0;
}

else if(checkboxSelected == YES)
{
    selValue = 1;
}


       NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:selValue]; 
    NSString *isSelected = [number stringValue];


 NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO reminders(name,event,date,tim,bfr,val,num,bod,grp) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\",\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")", fieldOne.text, fieldTwo.text,fieldThree.text,fieldFour.text,fieldFive.text,isSelected,fieldSix.text,textView.text,fieldSeven.text];
```

Get:

```
 remind.selString = [[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statment, 6)];

 NSString *one = remind.selString;
     NSNumber* i = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[one intValue]];;
     BOOL isOn = [i boolValue];

if(isOn){
   //set ON Image
}
else{
   //set OFF image
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,but I have a doubt.What is the syntax used in table for holding the value.I mean **CREATE TABLE reminders(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,Name VARCHAR(64),button ?)**,the question mark is what I need,Also while insertion we use **INSERT INTO reminders((name,event,button) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\",?)**.Is it the same format for button also,some clarification needed :P thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'm not clear why your doing this :isEqualToString:@"YES"];.Cant you just pass in the value as a string value like the rest? @"1",@"2"? Then it can be the same ,button VARCHAR(64)

Comment: Oh thank you very much but I want some thing like @"0" || @"1",I mean to check whether the button is selected or not,please help me out in this context too :)

Comment: See the code I edited it to show how to convert NSInteger to string.

Comment: To what should I set ON/OFF Image

Comment: If it is Every Year YES, if not NO. Your using an On Image and Off image correct?

Comment: isSelected can now be a string value like all the others. I changed the name. I just changed it back to isSelected

Comment: Actually I am setting the image to the button based on bool checkboxSelected value

Comment: Yeah sorry for lot of questions,getting little confused,should I implement both the code i.e. setting as well as the code above it,because I am pretty much confused that If I store a string value lets say selected 1,not selected 0.So how can it realize the button selection and display the same,can you please post the query also,thanks for the patience and concern :)

Comment: See the new edit, You query it the same way as the others in ReminderClass then convert it to a BOOL to check the Button state, ON/OFF and set your image accordingly as you did the first time.

Comment: Actually it is very much clear what you suggested.I am able to understand the idea behind the snippet.But let me make you clear so that you can clarify my doubt with ease.I have a page Add Reminder where the button is present.I have already set the image when the button is selected and in normal state.Now I have a page edit reminder where the user can edit.To get the data I used a model class ReminderClass.

Comment: Please see the **EDIT** part of code in my post. To get the data present in every field in add reminder page itself we will pass the data in **cellForRowAtIndexPath** to reminder class containing all the variables i.e. **reminderInstance.Name = textField.text**,like wise for all.Now how can I pass the same button state to reminderInstance.selString = ? which will do the trick.Here selString is of type selString,thanks in advance

Comment: OK so then what do you want? You've got the data and can set the button based on the return value.

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked perfect please see the change that I made to your answer.Thanks thanks once again :)

Answer (score 1):

if you get the remind.selString then save it in

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", remind.selString];
```

and then check it your status with

```
if([str isEqualToString:@"0"]){
// put your code here to set your images 
}
else{

}
```

Comment: Is this the code where I have to check before editing (navigating to controller) where the data is saved for the reminder instance

Comment: you have to write before you display the entire page. like after you get the data you have to do this functionality

Comment: Actually the answer given by Mr.Hubert Kunnemeyer worked.Hence I followed it thanks for the answer once again :)